# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined - scope issue

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a json blob I'm trying to parse and I'm having trouble.  Here's the example json:

```
let subscriptions = {
   "Channel-416025343279890452":{
      "PC":{
         "Game-1":[
            1
         ],
         "Game-2":[
            1
         ]
      },
      "XBOX":{
         "Game-2":[
            1
         ],
         "Game-3":[
            1,
            3
         ],
         "Game-4":[
            4,
            5,
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

My goal is to end up with a collection that identifies each platform for each game, like...

```
[
   "Game-1":[
      "PC",
      "XBOX",
   ]
]
```

My project uses lodash so I was hoping to get a more readable solution using that library...

```
let subs = this.subscriptions[this.channel.id];
var gamesAndCategories = [];
_.forOwn(subs, (gamesAndInterests, category) => {
    _.forOwn(gamesAndInterests, (interestId, game) => {
        gamesAndCategories[game].push(category);
    });
});
console.log(gamesAndCategories);
```

I'm running into `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. I've tried to swap out the arrow functions for `function () {}` with no luck.  I'm also wondering if there's an easier way to extract this data?  I don't have much control over the json structure and am new to lodash.

**How can I resolve this variable scope issue where I can build the array as I expect?**

Comment: Given `gamesAndCategories` is an empty array, why would you expect to be able to call `push` on _any_ index within it? Perhaps you meant `gamesAndCategories[game] = category` or just `gamesAndCategories.push(category)`

Comment: Your example result isn't a valid JS structure. Could you please clarify exactly what the result should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect all your *games-to-platforms* data using a reduce operation (no Lodash required)

1. Iterate all the key / value (platform / games) pairs
2. Iterate all the *game* keys in the *games* object
3. Collect the data in an object (or `Map`) keyed by the game with an array of platforms as the value

```js
const sub = {"PC":{"Game-1":[1],"Game-2":[1]},"XBOX":{"Game-2":[1],"Game-3":[1,3],"Game-4":[4,5]}}

const gamesAndCategories = Object.entries(sub)
  .reduce((map, [ platform, gameObj ]) => {
    Object.keys(gameObj).forEach(game => {
      const games = map[game] || (map[game] = [])
      games.push(platform)
    })
    return map
  }, Object.create(null))
  
console.log(gamesAndCategories)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a scope issue. You should assign initial values of `gamesAndCategories[game]`.

```js
let subscriptions = {
   "Channel-416025343279890452":{
      "PC":{
         "Game-1":[
            1
         ],
         "Game-2":[
            1
         ]
      },
      "XBOX":{
         "Game-2":[
            1
         ],
         "Game-3":[
            1,
            3
         ],
         "Game-4":[
            4,
            5
         ]
      }
   }
}

let subs = subscriptions["Channel-416025343279890452"];
var gamesAndCategories = {};
_.forOwn(subs, (gamesAndInterests, category) => {
    _.forOwn(gamesAndInterests, (interestId, game) => {
        if (gamesAndCategories[game] == undefined) {
            gamesAndCategories[game] = []
        }
        gamesAndCategories[game].push(category);
    });
});
console.log(gamesAndCategories);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```